# Get previous fragment at Onbackpressed

Tags: android

Situation is like this
Flow : Activity -> Fragment1 -> Fragment2 -> Fragment3
When H/W back button is clicked when fragment 1 ~ 3 is on screen, Acitivity pops up.

I want to know which fragment was previous one at the onbackpress method is called.

Code (Activity)

`public void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (!isFinishing()) {
            mFragmentManger.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.input_preference_contatiner, fragment).commit();
        }
    }`

Code(Fragment 1 2 3)

 `@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                InputPreferenceActivity inputPreferenceActivity = (InputPreferenceActivity) getActivity();
                inputPreferenceActivity.setFragment(new InputPreferenceStep1Fragment());
            }`

Comment: Are you adding the fragments or replacing them?

Comment: post some code please

Comment: I added code that I wrote

Answer (score 0):

When you are transitioning between Fragments, call `addToBackStack()` as part of your `FragmentTransaction`:

```
FragmentTransaction tx = fragmentManager.beginTransation();
tx.replace( R.id.fragment, new MyFragment() ).addToBackStack( "tag" ).commit();
```

If you require more detailed control (i.e. when some Fragments are visible, you want to suppress the back key) you can set an `OnKeyListener` on the parent view of your fragment:

```
//You need to add the following line for this solution to work; thanks skayred
fragment.getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
fragment.getView().requestFocus();
fragment.getView().setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
    {
        if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

put this Code in Fragment when you change the fragment

> addToBackStack(null)

in fragment change

```
            FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```